# React - edit state from reducer

Tags: reactjs

Using ReactJS / Redux / thunk, I can't get simple example working.

I can't get state from the reducer, or I don't know how to access it ?

I combine my reducers :

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import sites from './sitesReducer';
import session from './sessionReducer';
import cities from './citiesReducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    // short hand property names
    sites,
    cities,
    session
})

export default rootReducer;
```

Then create a store :

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import rootReducer from '../reducers'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

export default function configureStore() {
    return createStore(
        rootReducer,
        applyMiddleware(thunk)
    );
}
```

In citiesReducer :

```
import * as types from '../actions/actionTypes';
import initialState from './initialState';

export default function citiesReducer(state = initialState.cities, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case types.AUTOCOMPLETE_CITIES_SUCCESS:
            // it works, data is filled from my action (from ajax get)
            console.log(action.data)

            // here I guess state is not updated, I can't get it in HomePage
            return {
                ...state,
                cities: action.data
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

In my index.js file, I use router :

```
const store = configureStore();

render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={history}>
            <div>
                <Route exact path="/" render={() => (
                    auth.loggedIn() ? (
                        <HomePage />
                    ) : (
                        <Redirect to="/login"/>
                    )
                )}/>
                ....
```

In HomePage.js, I can't get store from context (?), so I use configureStore :

```
const store = configureStore();

class HomePage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context)
        // context is empty :(
        this.state = {
            value: ''
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <TextInput
                value={value}
                onChange={(event, value) => {
                    this.setState({ value })
                    if (value.length > 2) {
                        // call ajax action, which works 
                        this.props.actions.getCityByName(value);
                    }
                }}
            />
            <ul>
                {store.getState().cities.map(function(city, index){
                    return <li key={ index }>{city.title}</li>;
                })}
            </ul>
        )
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        actions: bindActionCreators(citiesActions, dispatch)
    };
}
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(HomePage);
```

The **store.getState().cities** in HomePage is never updated. I tried using **this.state.cities** too.
Is it because I can't access store from context ? because of router ? I use react-router v4. Or do I need to do something else to update and access state in my HomePage component ?

Sorry for large code. I tried to reduce *(ah ah !)* at maximum.

Comment: This is a weird setup. Where is your `mapStateToProps` function in `HomePage`? Why the `state` in `citiesReducer` is set to `state = initialState.cities` instead of `initialState`?

Comment: Pretty right for `mapStateToProps ` function, I forgot it and of course it didn't work. `initialState` contains several keys, I initiate all reducers with its own key. Thanks anyways, it seems to work !